# Public field in private class: "Field [FieldName] is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null"

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, null, compiler-warnings, default-value

I have a private class that looks like this:

```
private class PocoUserWithResourceId
{
    public USER User;
    public string ResourceId;
}
```

I do things with this class (within the same encapsulating public class), like:

```
var uQuery = from u in db.USERS.All()
select new PocoUserWithResourceId {User = u, ResourceId = arv.Resource_Id};
```

And I'm getting the warning:

> Field 'PocoUserWithResourceId.ResourceId' is never assigned to, and
>   will always have its default value null

What am I missing? I'm assigning the value in my LINQ to SQL code.

Comment: In your case it's safe to ignore the warning.

Comment: Is it just because I'm assigning property values during the declaration that the compiler doesn't see the fact that I'm using them?

Comment: The logic the compiler is using to generate the warnings is just not quite up to date with recent syntax additions to the C# language.

Comment: @Dave, what (new) syntax is the OP leveraging that would lead to this issue?

Comment: It's obviously not considering the object initializer syntax introduced in C#3 (or C#4 ?).

Comment: By the way, this isn't critical - in the whole scheme of things, the generation of warnings doesn't have to be 100% accurate.  The generation of accurate machine code from source code does have to be extremely close to 100% though.

Comment: You could get rid of the warning by creating a constructor for your class that accepts a user and resourceID and just sets the public properties.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it just because I'm assigning property values during the
>   declaration that the compiler doesn't see the fact that I'm using
>   them?

No, that's just because you're assigning [field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx) values, not [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) values ...

You have choice between 2 good practices :
- Use a constructor
- Use accessors (properties)

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily disable the warning for the specific case using #pragma

```
// turn it off
#pragma warning disable 0649
private class Foo
{
   public string FieldName
}
// turn it back on
#pragma warning restore 0649
```

To figure out what the error number is, examine the raw output or right click the warning and choose  Show Error Help.  You'll find the error buried in the URL (CS0649) even though the page itself has nothing to do with the warning.